# Supplying the values from first column of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, import

In one of the code snippet, the authors provide the input as:

```
variants = [ 'rs425277', 'rs1571149', 'rs1240707', 'rs1240708', 'rs873927', 'rs880051', 'rs1878745', 'rs2296716', 'rs2298217', 'rs2459994' ]
```

However I have similar values as one of the column in csv format. I would like to know how I can supply one of the column as input similar to above example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the csv file in pandas, and get the column you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, import your csv as a Pandas df.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Then, you can get a list from pandas dataframe column:

```
col_one_list = df['column_one'].tolist()
```